# error C2783: '_Ty &&std::forward(remove_reference<_Ty>::type &&) throw()' : could not deduce template argument for '_Ty'

Tags: c++, c++11, perfect-forwarding, forwarding-reference

I have a templated implementation of a concurrent queue that has a push function that looks like:

```
template <typename T>
class concurrent_queue
{
public:

    // other code...

    void push(const T& item)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> mlock(mutex);
        queue.push_back(std::forward(item));
        mlock.unlock();
        notEmpty.notify_one();
    }

private:

    std::deque<T>               queue;
    std::mutex                  mutex;
    // other stuff...
};
```

Later on, I instantiate it and use it like so:

```
concurrent_queue<c2Type> m_queue;  // c2 type is some struct declared previously
```

and then I try to push items on the queue and I get the afore mentioned compiler error:

```
c2Type c2message;

// fill in the message struct...
m_queue.push(c2message);
```

I've sucessfully used the queue before as part of a thread pool implementation where it stored `std::function` objects. I don't understand why it can't deduce the type in this case. Any thoughts?

Comment: `queue.push_back(std::forward(item));` there is no reason to forward a *reference to a constant `T`*. -- The reason for the error is that you have to supply the template argument for `std::forward` manually: `std::forward<T>(t)`, since it (is meant to) "restores" the value category of `t`, if `t` is a forwarding reference.

Comment: Thanks. I removed const and added the template argument and it solved the problem. If you add your comment as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: I think you should use `void push(T&& item)`, without `const` and as a universal reference (`&&`). And call `forward<T>` with the explicit `T`. If you want to keep the const you should also add it in the call to `forward<const T>`. See http://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers for more details about the mess with different kind of references.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Value categories like "lvalue" and "rvalue" are properties of expressions. Expressions that name variables are always lvalue-expressions, even if they name a variable that has the type *rvalue reference to `some_type`*.

We use lvalue-reference and rvalue-references to bind different categories of expressions: Per convention, we treat lvalue-references as *being bound to lvalues*, and rvalue-references as *being bound to rvalues*.

`std::forward` is intended to restore the value category of what we assume a reference refers to. For example:

```
int   i = 42;
int&  l = i;
int&& r = 21;

l // this expression is an lvalue-expression
r // this expression is an lvalue-expression, too (!)

std::forward<int& >(l) // this function-call expression is an lvalue-expression
std::forward<int&&>(r) // this function-call expression is an rvalue-expression
```

`std::forward`, being "an ordinary function", cannot restore the value category merely by using the argument. Both arguments are lvalue-expressions. You have to specify which value category you want to restore by manually supplying the template-argument.

This makes only sense if we have a reference where we don't know a priori whether it's an rvalue-reference or an lvalue-reference. That is the case when writing a function that uses *perfect forwarding* with *forwarding references*.

By the way, we want to restore the value category to allow another function to move from the argument we have received. If we receive an rvalue argument, we want to pass on an rvalue, to allow the called function to move.

---

For a function like the one in the OP:

```
void push(const T& item)
```

We know that `item` has the type *lvalue reference to `const T`*. Therefore, we don't need `std::forward`:

```
void push(const T& item) {
    // ...
    queue.push_back(item); // pass the lvalue argument as an lvalue
    // ...
}
```

If we add another overload:

```
void push(T&& item)
```

we still don't need `std::forward`, since the type of that parameter `item` is always *rvalue-reference to `T`* <sub>(assuming `T` is not a reference type)</sub>:

```
void push(T&& item) {
    // ...
    queue.push_back(std::move(item)); // pass the rvalue argument as an rvalue
    // ...
}
```

Only if we have something like

```
template<typename U>
void push(forwarding_reference<U> item)
```

where `forwarding_reference<U>` can be either an *lvalue-reference* or an *rvalue-reference*, then we need `std::forward`:

```
template<typename U>
void push(forwarding_reference<U> item) // not C++, read on
{
    // ...
    queue.push_back(std::forward<U>(item)); // pass lvalue arguments as lvalues
                                            // and rvalue arguments as rvalues
    // ...
}
```

Due to implementation details, we must write the above as:

```
template<typename U>
void push(U&& item) {
    // ...
    queue.push_back(std::forward<U>(item)); // pass lvalue arguments as lvalues
                                            // and rvalue arguments as rvalues
    // ...
}
```

Note that the above `U&& item` is *not* an rvalue-reference, but a forwarding reference. To get a forwarding reference, you need to have a function template with some template type parameter `X` and a function parameter of the form `X&& x`.

Comment: g++ accepts `template<typename T> using forwarding_reference = T&&;` as a forwarding reference by the way, but clang++ does not. :(

Comment: Awesome answer, this really cleared up some misconceptions I've had about forwarding that I haven't seen in other SO answers